# Texto responsivo dentro de uma Box

Tags: html, css

preciso coloca um texto dentro de um quadrado, por cima de uma imagem e que o texto se quebre quando chegar ao limite do quadro [IMAGEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doeeQ.png)

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Já usou o word-wrap ?
A propriedade CSS word-wrap é utilizada para especificar se o navegador pode ou não quebrar linhas dentro das palavras, afim de prevenir o vazamento quando do contrário uma sequencia de caracteres é muito longa para caber na caixa que o contém.
pode ser usada da seguinte forma , por exemplo se seu texto estiver em uma tag "p"

```
p { width: 13em; background: gold; word-wrap: break-word; }
```

onde :
Valores

normal

Indica que as linhas só podem quebrar em pontos de quebra normais de palavras.

break-word

Indica que as palavras normalmente inquebráveis podem ser quebrados em pontos arbitrários se não houver pontos de quebra de outra forma aceitáveis na linha.

fonte : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap